# Ionic App taking more time to load with splash screen and white screen

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile-application, ionic-native

I have created an Ionic app but the load time is too much and sometime white screen appears before loading.

How can i reduce the load time?

Issue i am facing as below:

1. If i keep value as 6000, i am getting the below error:

   `<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="6000" />`

Error:

```
Application Error - The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
```

2. If i increase the value as 60000, i am getting white screen after splash and the white screen is visible for around 10 to 15 seconds, then it disappears and the app loads.

Below is the config.xml details.

```
 <preference  name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true"/>
    <preference  name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false"/>
    <preference  name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000"/>
    <preference  name="SplashScreenDelay" value="6000"/>
    <preference  name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true"/>
    <preference  name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true"/>
    <preference  name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true"/>
    <preference  name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreenBackgroundColor" value="0x1d1c1e" />
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="6000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to note here. First, you've got `SplashScreenDelay` set to 60 seconds (60000 miliseconds). That's a very long time. According to [docs](https://ionic.io/docs/premier-plugins/splashscreen): "Amount of time in milliseconds to wait before automatically hide splash screen." Secondly, you have `AutoHideSplashScreen` set to `false`.

What's your end goal here? I'd recommend setting `AutoHideSplashScreen` to 'true'. Then decrease `SplashScreenDelay`.

If you want to control exactly when the splash screen disappears, you can.

1. Install the plugin if you don't have it (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/splash-screen).
2. Add to your constructor in your parent component (likely app.component.ts):
   `private splashScreen: SplashScreen`
3. Inside your component, you can choose when you want to hide the splash screen. For me I typically use it in `ngOnInit()`. Just use `this.splashScreen.hide();` to close the splash screen. Granted, you can use later lifecycle hooks depending on when you want the app to hide the splash screen.
4. At this point you can remove `AutoHideSplashScreen` from your config.xml.

Now to stop the white flash before, you'll need to add this to your config.xml:
`<preference name="SplashScreenBackgroundColor" value="0x1d1c1e" />`
This color is for a dark grey, but you can adjust it to whatever color you want.

Comment: I have updated the question after making the changes as suggested by you. Still the wait time to load the app is too much.

Comment: If you've also tried `this.splashScreen.hide()` and it doesn't work, you may have a different underlying issue. Ionic should not be taking a minute to load. I'd recommend using Inspect with Chrome Developer Tools (chrome://inspect/#devices) to check for errors and network calls. If you're using `cordova-serve-android`, the issue may be the connection between your computer and the device. Try cordova-build-android and install the apk. If it fires right up, that'll tell you. Cordova Serve is known to be buggy. I've had bad luck with it too.